# My react SPA navigation currently renders the page for about a second and then goes back to my Main page

Tags: reactjs

I am coding in react and my navigation will open the page I want and then immediately go back to the main page. I can't seem to wrap my head around what I might be doing wrong.

It is opening the new page so I feel like my ReactDOM Render below the main page is where everything is going wrong but I can't tell if it's just an issue with the way I've organized my code or the code itself.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";


 class Main extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
         <div> 
        <h1> React Playground </h1>

        <ul className="header">
            <li><a href="" onClick= {function () {
                    ReactDOM.render(<Playground />, document.getElementById('root'));
            }}>Playground</a></li>
            <li><a href="" onClick={function () {
                    ReactDOM.render(<Technology />, document.getElementById('root'));
            }}>Technology</a></li>
            <li><a href="" onClick={function () {
                    ReactDOM.render(<Library />, document.getElementById('root'));
            }}>Library</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
        );
    }
 }

 ReactDOM.render(
  <Main />, 
  document.getElementById("root")
  );

//here is the Playground component for the Playground Page

class Playground extends React.Component {
  render() {
      document.title = "My Playground";

    return (
      <div>
        <header>
        <h1> My Playground </h1>
        </header>

        <nav>
        <ul className="header">
            <li><a href="" onClick= {function () {
                    ReactDOM.render(<Playground />, document.getElementById('root'));
            }}>Playground</a></li>

            <li><a href="" onClick={function () {
                    ReactDOM.render(<Technology />, document.getElementById('root'));
            }}>Technology</a></li>

            <li><a href="" onClick={function () {
                    ReactDOM.render(<Library />, document.getElementById('root'));
            }}>Library</a></li>

        </ul>
        </nav>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

//here is the Technology component for the Technology Page
class Technology extends React.Component {

  render() {
      document.title = "Fun Technology ";

    return (
      <div> 
        <h1> Fun Technology </h1>

        <ul className="header">
            <li><a href="" onClick= {function () {
                    ReactDOM.render(<Playground />, document.getElementById('root'));
            }}>Playground</a></li>

            <li><a href="" onClick={function () {
                    ReactDOM.render(<Technology />, document.getElementById('root'));
            }}>Technology</a></li>

            <li><a href="" onClick={function () {
                    ReactDOM.render(<Library />, document.getElementById('root'));
            }}>Library</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//here is the Library component for the Library page

class Library extends React.Component {

  render() {
      document.title = "Personal Library";

    return (
      <div> 
        <h1> Personal Library </h1>

        <ul className="header">
            <li><a href="" onClick= {function () {
                    ReactDOM.render(<Playground />, document.getElementById('root'));
            }}>Playground</a></li>

            <li><a href="" onClick={function () {
                    ReactDOM.render(<Technology />, document.getElementById('root'));
            }}>Technology</a></li>

            <li><a href="" onClick={function () {
                    ReactDOM.render(<Library />, document.getElementById('root'));
            }}>Library</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/7jk19zo9yq).

- Your first issue I think is using multiple `ReactDOM.render`s. That's not the intended use case I'm afraid. You're supposed to use that once.
- The second problem I see is duplicating your navigation three times. If you extract that into its own component and call it `Navigation`, you can render it only once. Like:

  ```
  function Navigation(props) {
      return (
    <ul className="header">
      <li>
        <a href="#" onClick={() => props.onClick("playground")}>
          Playground
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" onClick={() => props.onClick("technology")}>
          Technology
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" onClick={() => props.onClick("library")}>
          Library
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  )}
  ```

Then you can use it this way:

```
function Main() {
  const [page, setPage] = useState("playground");
  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation onClick={setPage} />
      {page === "playground" && <Playground />}
      {page === "technology" && <Technology />}
      {page === "library" && <Library />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

- If you don't wanna use `react-router` for the route-based component rendering, then you need to introduce `state` and toggle the component based on the `state`. In the above `Main` component I have one state which can hold `playground`, `technology` or `library` and based on the current value we render the appropriate component.